# NaN Multiplication Result When Negative Number is Contained within a Vector

Tags: r, nan

I am experience a problem calculating the result when putting a vector to the power of a decimal. The problem is more specifically that negative numbers in the vector come back as NAN. This also happens if I assign the negative number to a variable. Some examples to explain:

```
> -5.718301^2.85
[1] -143.9498

> test<--5.718301
> test
[1] -5.718301
> test^2.85
[1] NaN

> c(5.718301)^2.85
[1] 143.9498
> c(-5.718301)^2.85
[1] NaN
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? And any way around it? The vector in question may have positive and negative values, therefore, I can't assign a negative sign after.

Thanks in advance,
Aran

Comment: It's in the FAQ: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-powers-of-negative-numbers-wrong_003f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real valued solution to `(-5.718301)^2.85` and so `NaN` is the correct answer.

```
> (-5.718301)^2.85
[1] NaN
```

What you are attempting here is akin to asking for the square root of a negative number.

When you successfully evaluated

```
-5.718301^2.85
```

the precedence of the operators meant that this was equivalent to

```
-(5.718301^2.85)
```

and of course that is well-defined.

Comment: Good explanation, +1. Note that you can evaluate `as.complex(-5.718301)^2.85` which gives `-128.2602+65.3518i`